# Firebase dynamic link lifespan

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I create Firebase dynamic links programmatically and can share them with other application users (I invite them to join some of my entities, for example). But here is the problem: users are able to resend the link to other users and I am not able to control it.

Is there any mech to make dynamic links disposable (one-off) or adjust the link with some lifespan timer? How do you handle the case when you want to control the link distribution?

I've checked Firebase documentation and it's said that the dynamic link can not expire.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you consider checking [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#create_invitation_links) step and the succeeding ones as these demonstrate how you can create a referral link up to the retrieval of the UID value. If you have generated a short link, this might be the next steps you’ll want/need to implement with your client application code.